# Cannot change the width profile of a brush stroke in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, brush

I'm learning to use Illustrator and I've maid a brush stroke, but I cannot change the width profile of the brush stroke.

This is what I do: I select the stroke I've made with my custom brush, I go to the panel at the top, I change the width profile of the stroke but it doesn't work.

Even if I select any width profile and I use the brush, the brush stroke is always the same.

[image: screenshot of setting and result]

What is the problem?

Comment: Update: In the Appearance Panel Menu, "New Art Has Basic Appearance" is not checked.

Answer (score 3):

You can only set a custom width profile or adjust the width (using the width tool) of a stroke with either a basic brush (a.k.a. no brush), an art brush or a pattern brush... The "5 pt. Round" brush you have set is a calligraphic brush so a width profile simply won't work.

Comment: What is a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can *change* the type of brush stroke you're using under the Properties panel. From there, change the Brush setting to "basic". You can then change the width profile and arrows like a normal pen line, but you can't keep any special brush types.

Now, why they don't let you just use "basic" for your brush type in the first place is beyond me.